# Eclipse C cannot open output file file.exe access denied

Tags: c, eclipse, access-denied

I have a strange problem with eclipse, when I want to build a file I get the error:

```
c:/sysgcc/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Blok 2 week 1a.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I only get this error when I have at least build the file once successfully. I have looked if the file was still running(in task manager, debug view, console), but it isn't. The error does not go away after closing eclipse. Only after rebooting my computer I am able to build the file again.

I have really no idea how I could solve this problem. I hope there is someone who could help me with this.

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Try not to use tags that no one is following, such as build-error

Comment: Try to diagnose the problem using a tool like Handle http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx BTW, do you have McAfee antivirus (just kidding... maybe not).

Comment: oké i could try that. No I don't use McAfee I use Norman, why? Is this a common problem for McAfee?

Comment: Just to clarify - you say `I only get this error when I have at least build the file once successfully` - So this means you did **not** run the program?

Comment: Sorry I was not completely clear, but yes I have run the program

Comment: This is a common problem for any antivirus.